# Using unsigned long long instead of float to prevent wrapping

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-point, long-integer

I have an application in which I am using a certain class that has a method to return current elapsed time to me.

```
unsigned long long getCurrentElapsedTime(){
}
```

`Unsigned long long` is used instead of `float` in the above class because `float` wraps (changes to expo form) after running for a certain time (~1 hour).
Earlier, I was using the method from the class that returned `float` of seconds (1.112, 1.336 and so on) for my program.

```
float getElapsedTime(){
}
```

I was using the above method in my program as follows:

```
float startTime, deltaTime;
starttime = getElapsedTime();

On Some event
deltaTime = getElapsedtime() - startTime;
if(deltaTime > 1.0f){
//do something
}
```

I have this `getCurrentElapsedTime()` method now that returns `unsigned long long` integer to me which is not wrapped till a long time.
I have to use this method in my application in similar manner I used float but I am confused how I should be converting `unsigned long long` to `float` so that I don't get exponent format digits.
For my application, I was earlier using `float` that had the following format digits ( 1.123, 2.345, 3.737, etc.)

If I have a very long `unsigned long long` number which I try to convert to float, I would probably get the same problem again (and the float would be in expo form)
How do I tackle this problem? Is there something similar in decimals that I could convert to from `unsigned long long` without getting into wrapping problem?

Comment: The exponential form is not a matter of using `float`s, it's just `iostream` making assumptions about what kind of formatting the user wants to see.

Comment: Why do you now want to go back to floats? Just keep all time in long integers.

Comment: 1 - It's not clear what your 'conversion' should look like. An `unsigned long long` is an integer, why would you want to convert that to a floating point number? 2 - You can get rid of the exp-notation when printing floats, but that will result in trailing zeros that give the impression of precision that isn't there. 3 - What's wrong with exp-notation anyways?

Comment: @H2CO3 `iostream` doesn't make any assumptions.  It does what you tell it.  It obviously has to start in some state, however (but given the options for outputting floating point, who would ever output floating point without specifying at least the format and the precision).

Comment: @JamesKanze Assumption: "if x > 100000000, print it as 1e7 instead of 10000000 because people like compact forms more".

Comment: @H2CO3 I'd say almost the opposite.  People prefer fixed format, in general, but it's not appropriate for very large or very small numbers.  So the default format uses fixed when appropriate (for some more or less arbitrary definition of "appropriate"), and scientific otherwise.  This format is also appropriate (with adequate precision) when serializing to text format.  For human consumption, however, you'd _never_ output floating point without specifying fixed or scientific, and the precision.  Usually with custom, application specific manipulators.

Answer (score 0):

Float does not "change" to any "expo fo". In fact, an `unsigned long long` will at some point overflow and *wrap* back to 0. A `float` will not. It will just not differ from the previous float value anymore if you add too small increments. A float is lossy, but it can represent values such as "infinite". A long is lossless, but finite.

It's probably your *output function* that changes formatting at a certain scale. But it's a matter of how you *print* your numbers!

```
# Don't mind the python syntax, please:
print "Different format strings: %.3f %e %f" % (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
Different format strings: 1.000 1.000000e+00 1.000000
```

**Same number, different output**

However, **what is your time source**? Use the *native type of your time source* (which will likely be a `long`) You cannot improve precision just by converting this to another type.

Comment: Not that it matters, but you're Python's out of date:-).  In C++, of course, `std::cout << 1.0 << std::fixed << 1.0 << ' ' << std::scientific << 1.0 << std::endl;`.  (You should also mention that `float` doesn't _wrap_, ever, but `unsigned long long` does.)